# Establish remote SSL connection after or before local user connection for SSL wrapper?

Tags: c#, networking, ssl, tcp

I'm trying to make a `stunnel` clone in C# just for fun. The main loop goes something like this (ignore the catch-everything-and-do-nothing try-catches just for now)

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator;
            TcpListener a = new TcpListener (9999);
            a.Start ();
            while (true) {
                Console.Error.WriteLine ("Spinning...");
                try {
                    TcpClient remote = new TcpClient ("XXX.XX.XXX.XXX", 2376);
                    SslStream ssl = new SslStream(remote.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Validator));
                    ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("mirai.ca");
                    TcpClient user = a.AcceptTcpClient ();
                    new Thread (new ThreadStart(() => {
                        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
                        try{
                            forward(user.GetStream(), ssl); //forward is a blocking function I wrote
                        }catch{}
                    })).Start ();
                } catch {
                    Thread.Sleep (1000);
                }
            }
```

I found that if I do the remote SSL connection, as I did, before waiting for the user, then when the user connects the SSL is already set up (this is for tunneling HTTP so latency is pretty important). On the other hand, my server closes long-inactive connections, so if no new connection happens in, say, 5 minutes, everything locks up.

What is the best way?

Also, I observe my program generating as much as 200 threads, which of course means that context-switching overhead is pretty big and sometimes results in the whole thing just blocking for seconds, even with just one user tunneling through the program. My forward function goes, in a gist, like

```
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>in.CopyTo(out))).Start();
    out.CopyTo(in);
```

of course with lots of error handling to prevent broken connections from holding up forever. This seems to stall a lot though. I can't figure how to use asynchronous methods like `BeginRead` which should help according to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any kind of proxy server (including an `stunnel` clone), opening the backend connection *after* you accept the frontend connection is clearly much simpler to implement.

If you pre-open backend connections in anticipation of receiving frontend connections, you can certainly save an RTT (which is good for latency), but you have to deal with the issue you hinted at: the backend will close idle connections. At any time that you receive a frontend connections, you run the risk that the backend connection that you are about to associate with this frontend connection and which has been opened some time ago is too old to use and may be closed by the backend. You will have to manage a pool of currently open backend connections and periodically close and refresh them when they become idle for too long. There is even a race condition where if the backend decided the connection has been idle too long and decides to close it but the proxy server receives a new frontend connection at the same time, the frontend may decide to forward a request through the backend connection *while* the backend is closing this connection. That means that you must be able to know a priori how long backend connections can be idle for before the backend will close them (you must know what the timeout values that are configured on the backend are set to) so you can give them up just before the backend will decide they are too old.

So in summary: pre-opening backend connections will save an RTT versus opening them only on demand, but it is a lot of work, including subtle connection pool management that it quite tough to implement bug-free. Up to you to judge if the extra complexity is worth it.

By the way, concerning your comment about handling several hundred simultaneous connections, I recommend implementing such an I/O-bound program as a proxy server based around an event loop instead of based around threads. Basically, you use non-blocking sockets and process events in a single thread (e.g. "this socket has new data waiting to be forwarded to the other side") instead of spawning a thread for each connection (which can get expensive both in thread creation and context switches). In order to scale such an event-based model to multiple CPU cores, you can start a small number of parallel threads of processes (more or less one per CPU core) which each handle many hundreds (or thousands) of simultaneous connections.

Comment: As I said, I really really want to use async methods, but seeing that all the async methods are really low level and use hard-to-manage byte buffers, I really want a heads-up on how to do it. Doing it synchronously is just a big while loop of reading and writing, but how bout async?

Comment: Yeah, there's no question that an async event loop is more complicated to program. You have to keep state in your data structures about the incoming and outgoing buffers for each socket, and which ones are ready to forward data and which are not. But I think the async vs. sync question is secondary to the main point of your question about whether or not to pre-open backend connections.

Comment: Well, I might be doing something wrong. This is not supposed to scale to thousands of users - in fact just one user, translating browser requests from localhost to ssl. It stills stalls a lot and degrades in performance over time, and the thread count in the long run gets more and more (probably some threads stall and never recover). Can't see any hint in the code though: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4580d8ff3c6e9ea38090

Comment: (Also, note that an SSL connection needs *three* RTTs. `stunnel` pre-opens connections quite well, and my toy program feels far more sluggish than `stunnel`. Real world usage is a program that I want to distribute without needing to bundle stunnel and all the huge libraries that come with it (especially problematic on Mac))

Comment: An SSL connection doesn't require 'three RTTs'. If you're including the SSL handshake, it is more like ten.

Comment: Yes, the handshake is what I meant. The way I wrote it it needs to handshake all over again for each connection.

Comment: Never mind, fixed the stalling problem. Turned out I was keeping around dead connections without closing them (unless an error happened, which is about the opposite of most people's errors), which meant the browser had to try communicating through the old dead keep-alive socket, time out, before knowing to open an new socket. And only when the browser tries to use dead sockets does my program realize they are dead and kills their thread. Which means basically that thousands of zombie threads in a slow loop, which of course messes up context switching.